# Who can solve my text positioning problem in my colored tabu header row?

Tags: tables, tabu

I've a positioning problem in my tabu header. If I define the text color with `rowfont`, the text in that row will jumping around like a rabbit.

```
\documentclass[]{scrlttr2}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{TableHeaderColor}{HTML}{444444}
\definecolor{TableHeaderBackgroundColor}{HTML}{EEEEEE}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabu} to \textwidth {c X}
        \rowfont{\bfseries\footnotesize\color{TableHeaderColor}}
        \taburowcolors{TableHeaderBackgroundColor .. TableHeaderBackgroundColor}
        Header & Test \\ \hline
        \taburowcolors{white .. white}
        Bla & bla \\ \hline
        \rowfont{\bfseries\footnotesize\color{TableHeaderColor}}
        \taburowcolors{TableHeaderBackgroundColor .. TableHeaderBackgroundColor}
        Footer & bla
    \end{tabu}

\end{document}
```

The resoult is the following:
[image]

## Update

According to Gonzalo Medina's answer I did this changes:

```
\begin{tabu} to \textwidth {X[1,m,c] X[9,m]}
```

The positioning is still not perfect. The baseline isn't the same.

[image]

## Update #2

After I added `\strut` as Gonzalo Medina recommended, I've still the problem if I'm using `\usepackage{lmodern}`.

[image]

Comment: PLease complement your code to a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: Okay, just a moment.

Comment: This seems to be an issue with the column specification `X` and `\rowfont`, the baseline of the normal text is used as the top anchor for the `X` column.

Comment: How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One option is to change the `c` column specification; for example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabu}

\definecolor{TableHeaderColor}{HTML}{444444}
\definecolor{TableHeaderBackgroundColor}{HTML}{EEEEEE}

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{tabu} to \textwidth {X[1,m,c] X[9,m]}
\rowfont{\strut\bfseries\footnotesize\color{TableHeaderColor}}
\taburowcolors{TableHeaderBackgroundColor .. TableHeaderBackgroundColor}
Header & Testggg \\ \hline
\taburowcolors{white .. white}
Bla & bla \\ \hline
\rowfont{\strut\bfseries\footnotesize\color{TableHeaderColor}}
\taburowcolors{TableHeaderBackgroundColor .. TableHeaderBackgroundColor}
Footer & bla
\end{tabu}

\end{document}
```

Depending on you actual needs, the specification might need some adjustments.

[image]

A test using TikZ to draw a line showing the baseline:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{tikz}

\definecolor{TableHeaderColor}{HTML}{444444}
\definecolor{TableHeaderBackgroundColor}{HTML}{EEEEEE}

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{tabu} to \textwidth {X[1.5,m,c] X[8.5,m]}
\rowfont{\strut\bfseries\footnotesize\color{TableHeaderColor}}
\taburowcolors{TableHeaderBackgroundColor .. TableHeaderBackgroundColor}
Aufwand & Beschr \\ \hline
\taburowcolors{white .. white}
Bla & bla \\ \hline
\rowfont{\strut\bfseries\footnotesize\color{TableHeaderColor}}
\taburowcolors{TableHeaderBackgroundColor .. TableHeaderBackgroundColor}
Footer & bla
\end{tabu}

\noindent\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw[red] (0,29.5pt) -- (\textwidth,29.5pt);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It helped to fix the problem almost. I've done an update of my question.

Comment: @Sam new updated (changing the position of `\strut`).

Comment: Thank you for your update. It works with the given setting. Unfortunately I use another font `\usepackage{lmodern}`. With that font there is still a difference..

Comment: @Sam sorry, but I can't see the difference using my last updated code. Can you add an example to your question showing the difference?

Comment: I've updated my question.

Comment: I want to thank you again for your help..! working now for two hours on this really stupid problem. I just want another text color.

Comment: @Sam I still cant't reproduce the problem. Since you added just an image but not the code used, I used some dummy text in the second code of my updated answer. I also used a red rule to check the baseline and, as you can see, there's no problem in my new code. Can you please add the actual code showing the problem?

Comment: You're right.. can't believe it.. it's Evince my pdf viewer!

Comment: If you struggeling someday around here in Zurich, let me know. You'll get a free beer :)